# How to achieve this Photoshop effect on a letter?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'd like to know how this beautiful "letter image" I found on web was done:

[image]

I have attempted with Photoshop CS6 using two Layers and a nice texture to achieve the text, but the result is approximate.

If somebody is so kind to explain to me in detail how organize only the layers (no background)?

Comment: Hello Sibylla, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Please include an image of your attempts and where you get stuck. We are visual people here. Also, pleas try and focus your question on a single issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. If an article or a book could be written about your question's answer, it's most probably too broad and will be closed as such. If you have any questions, please have a look at the [help]. Don't be discouraged, we're a nice bunch here. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is made using the 3D option in Photoshop CS6 extended or Photoshop CC. Try to look for similar design tutorials on the web, working with "3D option" maybe they will bring you closer to you goal. GL

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I tried and got this far, it's close but not perfect.

Use the blending mode, add texture color and inner shadows.
Now use the bevel and embross, keep depth and soften at 1, use size according to the font size.

Now you will have to experiment with the rest of it. On the shading menu, push highlights:100 shadow:0, change gloss-contours and angles. Goto contour menu and play with the settings. I'm not an expert and not sure how the contours work, and this is as close as i could get. Also you can duplicate the layer, change fill to 0% and hide pattern/shadow/color,etc. except Bevel and embross, and make a few changes to its setting. This will give you an extra layer of gloss on the text.

Hope this helps.